# Command permissions Discord.net

Tags: discord.net

user type : "test", 
if user have role "`vip`" then message show up "`you have permission`"

else "`you dont have permission`"

my code :

```
  Public Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task

   If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
   Else 
   If message.Content.Contains("test") Then

            Dim userName As SocketGuildUser
            Dim user = TryCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser)
            Dim role = (TryCast(user, IGuildUser)).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "vip")

            If Not userName.Roles.Contains(role) Then

                Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you have permission")
            Else
                Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you dont have permission")
            End If


        End If

   End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, for creating commands in general, you should consider using the **[Command Service](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/intro.html)** that's provided in Discord.Net, instead of If/Else checks in your message received event handler.

There's also an error in your code. You declare a `userName` variable, but never actually assign anything to it. Yet you attempt to do `userName.Roles`

Solution:

```vb
If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
    Return
ElseIf message.Content.Contains("test") Then

    Dim user = TryCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser)

    'If casting the user to a SocketGuildUser was not successful, then exit
    If user Is Nothing Then Return 'This can occur if a user message the bot via Direct Messages

    'Using "Any" returns true if a match is found, false otherwise
    If user.Roles.Any(Function(role) role.Name.Equals("VIP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
        Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you have permission")
    Else
        Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you dont have permission")
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

a simply trick, if your vip's member can count as not many member's you can select them id's to let them permission.

```
If message.Content.Contains("test") Then
If message.Author.Mention = "<@!ID>" Then  'vip's permission |OrElse statement
Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you have permission")
Else
Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you dont have permission")
End If
```